# Android development R cannot be resolved to a variable (no resource found error)

Tags: java, android, resources, r.java-file

Yesterday I was working on my Android app and it was running fine. But today when i opened it, I am getting the error `R cannot be resolved to a variable` and i am not sure why this is happening. In the console i am getting this error `[2014-03-29 11:04:59 - RockPaperScissors] C:\Users\hosfo_000\workspace2\RockPaperScissors\res\menu\main.xml:6: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'title' with value '@string/action_settings').`
 
Does anyone have any ideas what might be causing this? I already tried cleaning the project but that did not work.

EDIT

Line 6 of my main.XML is `<item` So i added the rest of that item. My entire main.xml consists of this item.

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="never"/>
```

Comment: Are you using the right R? Check to make sure you're not using android.R

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Are you sure the String action_settings exists in the res/values/strings?

Add this to the res/values/strings file

```
<resources>
<string name="action_settings">Action Settings</string>
<string name="app_name">The name of your app</string>
</resources>
```

Comment: no, that file is empty. Is that the problem? And how would i fix it?

Comment: @RyanHosford yes, that is the problem, please see my edit and if the answer has been useful please accept it or/and upvote it :-)

Comment: I have. Any other ideas?

Comment: @RyanHosford OK, save your project, then go to Project->Clean and select your project and press OK

Comment: @RyanHosford please see in the gen folder of your project, under the package name you should see R.java. do you see it?

Comment: no. Under the package name all I see is buildconfig.java

Comment: @RyanHosford R does not generate if there is some error in your XML or if one of your resources is named incorrectly (use ONLY lowercase letter). What does your console say now?

Comment: the console hasn't changed. How do i make it update?

Comment: @try to post a screeshoot of your console

Comment: I tried exiting eclipse and reopening, unfortunately the console was cleared. I took a screenshot of the problems tab which was saying the same thing as the console. Link to Screenshot: [link](http://imgur.com/r1uBogo)

Comment: You have another string missing in your `res/values/strings` file please see my edit

Comment: @RyanHosford please add `<string name="app_name">The name of your app</string>` to the `res/values/strings` file

Answer (score 0):

if the file is empty, you need to create it....

put this in the above named resource file.

```
<string name="action_settings">Your Text Here</string>
```

90% of the time the R error is because of an xml error

```
C:\Users\hosfo_000\workspace2\RockPaperScissors\res\menu\main.xml:6: error: Error:
```

Comment: I don't think there is an XML error, because everything worked fine yesterday

Comment: whats in line six? a reference to the above string... you need to make sure your spelling is correct in the string and then clean your project

Comment: I added your code to the main.xml and the error is still there

Comment: you want to open your resources folder, and then open the strings xml, and put it there. if theres nothing else in your strings folder it should look like this

Comment: <resources>
<string name="action_settings">Action Settings</string>
</resources>

Comment: added line 6 of main.xml to question in form of edit

Comment: Yes, strings.xml looks like that.

Comment: does it compile? you should at least get a different error now. whats it say in the logcar when you run it?